# Javascript code passed to MS Edge to click elements and extract text does not work

Tags: javascript, webview2

I am a .NET (C#) programmer with no background in javascript trying to automate mouse clicks and text extraction. I am using MS Edge as a control and passing javascript to it from C#.

Here is the page I want to automate: [link](https://maxroll.gg/guides/firebird-mirror-image-wizard-guide/2#variants). Scroll mid-page to the **Variants** section, you will see nested tabs. The idea is to click an outer tab and then click each inner tab it contains, and repeat for each outer tab. Here is a gif of the mouse clicks done manually: [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOp2H.gif).
For the extraction part I'd like to extract the text right under each mouse click in the gif. For e.g. for the first outer tab and its nested tabs, I should get "Nephalem Rifts", "Wizard", "Enchantress".

Retrieving the number of outer tabs, clicking each one and getting their text labels works.
Retrieving the number of inner tabs works, but clicking and extracting their text label does not work.

Here's my js code so far: {i}, {j} and {k} are integer variables resolved at runtime before passing to MS Edge. Assume {i} is always 0. {j} and {k} refer to the indices of the outer and inner tabs respectively.

**Number of outer tabs**:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab').length;
```

**Click an outer tab**:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab')[{j}].click();
```

**Extract the text label of an outer tab**:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab')[{j}].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
```

**Number of inner tabs**: ("" resolves to " before the string is passed to Edge)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style=""display: block;""').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode').length;
```

The following code **DOES NOT** **work**.

**Click an inner tab**: (when there are 2 inner tabs, the 2nd is never clicked. I pause execution for 1.5 seconds in C# after each click)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style=""display: block;""').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode')[k].click();
```

**Read the text label of an inner tab**: (returns *null*)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style=""display: block;""').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode')[k].getElementsByClassName('d3p-name')[0].innerText;
```

1. Please explain why it's not working and provide the correct code.
2. What tool/IDE would you use to debug and execute such javascript against a live (not locally hosted) webpage?
3. I dumped the DOM snapshot to a local file. What tool/IDE would you use to debug and execute such javascript against a local file?

Thanks!

Comment: To your last questions: Have you tried pressing 'F12' to bring up the developer tool? Choosing 'Sources' selecting your javascript file, you set breakpoints and step through your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the code, please try now. i hard coded the indices to run in browser, you can replace it with your indices

**for clicking tabs**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[0].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style="display: block;"').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode')[0].click();
```

**for reading texts from tabs**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[0].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style="display: block;"').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode')[1].getElementsByClassName('d3p-name')[0].innerText;
```

there is issue with your css selectors:

```
querySelector('div[style=""display: block;""')
```

**i fixed here**

```
querySelector('div[style="display: block;"')
```

*developers tool is the best debugger for debugging clientside issues.

Comment: I mentioned in the OP that "" was resolved to " in C# before being passed to MS Edge. So my code and your corrections are exactly the same, and do not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `querySelector` searching for '**style=**' you will only match elements that have that exact style, meaning only 'display: block'! Elements do always have more than one style, which means they won't be matched.

**The solution is to use the 'contains' selector (`*=`) instead.**

So you inner tab selector should look like this:

```
@"document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].querySelector('div[style*=""display: block;""]').getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode').length;"
```

Now it should match all elements that contains the 'display: block;' style even when they have plenty of other styles too.

**Important note: This will only work, if you have set the style on the element using the `style` *attribute*!** I f you have set the style using other css like classes, it won't work, even when the class contains `display: block;`.

If you have set the style using a class you should query for that instead.

And finally: **The universal solution**:

Using `getComputedStyle` works no matter how you have set the style, since it checks the actual style. The syntax is a bit different:

```
@"[...document.getElementsByClassName('advgb-tabs-wrapper')[{i}].getElementsByClassName('advgb-tab-body-wrapper')[0].children].filter(value =>
    {
        return getComputedStyle(value).display !== 'none';
    }).getElementsByClassName('d3p-mode')[k].getElementsByClassName('d3p-name')[0].innerText;"
```

This code will first convert the `children` list to an array and filter that array (`display` must not be 'none').